# Spark mapPartition output object size coming larger than expected

Tags: apache-spark

I am storing the output of mapPartitions in a ListBuffer and exposing its iterator as the output. The output is a list of Long tuples(Tuple2). When I check the size of the object using Spark's SizeEstimator.estimate method it comes out to 80 bytes per record/tuple object(calculating this by "size of ListBuffer object/# records"). This I think is too huge for a Tuple2 object of long type(two 8 byte longs + some object overhead memory). Any ideas why this is so and how to reduce the memory captured by output? I am sure I am missing something obvious.

Also, these ListBuffer object are getting too huge for memory leading to memory and disk spills causing bad performance. Any ideas on how I can just simply write the output of mapPartitions without storing the whole output as an in-memory object. Each input record to mapPartitions can generate 0 or more output records, so I think I cannot use "rdd.map" function iterator. I am not sure even if that will help my cause.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var outputRDD = sortedRDD.mapPartitionsWithIndex((partitionNo,p) => { 
      var outputList = ListBuffer[(Long,Long)]() 
      var inputCnt: Long = 0; 
      var outputCnt: Long = 0; 
  while (p.hasNext) { 
      inputCnt = inputCnt + 1; 
    val tpl = p.next() 
    var partitionKey = "" 
    try{ 
      partitionKey = tpl._1.split(keyDelimiter)(0)                          //Partition key 
    }catch{ 
      case aob : ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException => { 
        println("segmentKey:"+partitionKey); 
      } 
    }   
    val value = tpl._2 
    var xs: Array[Any] = value.toSeq.toArray; 
    //value.copyToArray(xs); 

    val xs_string : Array[String] = new Array[String](value.size); 
    for(i <- 0 to value.size-1){ 
      xs_string(i) = xs(i) match { case None => "" 
                                   case null => "" 
                                   case _ =>  xs(i).toString() 
                                 } 
    } 

    val outputTuples = windowObject.process(partitionKey, xs_string); 

            if(outputTuples != null){ 
                    for (i <- 0 until outputTuples.size()) { 
                            val outputRecord = outputTuples.get(i) 
                            if (outputRecord != null) { 
                                    outputList += ((outputRecord.getProfileID1 , outputRecord.getProfileID2)) 
                                    outputCnt = outputCnt +1; 
                            } 
                    } 
            }   
  } 

      if(debugFlag.equals("DEBUG")){    
            logger.info("partitionNo:"+ partitionNo + ", input #: "+ inputCnt +", output #: "+ outputCnt+", outputList object size:" + SizeEstimator.estimate(outputList)); 
      } 

      outputList.iterator 

}, false)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListBuffer` usually takes more spaces than `ArrayBuffer` because it creates a list node for each item in the list. However, Tuple2[Long, Long] usually takes 72 bytes (at least in my laptop) because of the object overhead. So you probably won't save much after replacing `ListBuffer` with `ArrayBuffer`.

For the second question, you can use `RDD.flatMap` to map a record to a sequence results .It avoids putting the results of a whole partition into `outputList`.